# Blogger Title Link Import via XML

Tags: xml, blogger

I am generating the below xml format in python to bulk import posts to blogger. I have seen that blogger has an option to also set the title link for the post, when using the web form.

[image: blogger link form]

Do you know how i could modify the below xml to also include the title link?

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns0:feed xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
> <ns0:generator>Blogger</ns0:generator>
> <ns0:entry>
> <ns0:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008/kind#post" />
> <ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="CATEGORY C" />
> <ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="CATEGORY D" />
> <ns0:id>Sample Blog Post</ns0:id><ns0:content type="html">Blogger CONTENT 2</ns0:content> 
> <ns0:published>2019-10-30T03:22:00.001-07:00</ns0:published> 
> <ns0:title type="html">Sample Blog Post</ns0:title> 
> </ns0:entry>
> </ns0:feed>
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title Link is saved as `related` link in the exported XML. The following format will work -

```
....
<ns0:published>2019-10-30T03:22:00.001-07:00</ns0:published> 
<ns0:link href='https://google.com/' rel='related'></ns0:link>
<ns0:title type="html">Sample Blog Post</ns0:title> 
....
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Do you if this is documented anywhere? Again thanks.

Comment: There is no direct mention about the title link specifically but this post - https://www.timbroder.com/2007/07/howto-get-blogger-feeds-using-python.html by @timbroder (https://stackoverflow.com/users/647343/timbroder) will be helpful